# android OSM/OSMdroid open street maps not loading tiles offline

Tags: java, android, dictionary, openstreetmap, osmdroid

I've created a very simple mapping application using osmdroid. I've set up the mapview to use offline maps only `mapView.setUserDataConnection(false);`
 the problem i'm having is that tiles are either not loading and leaving a grey box or loading very very slowly making different tiles on the map appear fuzzy. 
Does anyone know why this is happening or have a fix for it??

Comment: You need to say how your trying to integrate your offline map data.  What format is it? where your trying to put it? what tile provider you have setup...  It want happen by magic.

Comment: I just have mapView.setTileSource(TileSourceFactory.MAPNIK); is this not enough?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have this problem with version 3.0.7 , But was solved by changing to version 3.0.5
You should revert to 3.0.5 being the downloadable jar
from this link : 
https://osmdroid.googlecode.com/files/osmdroid-android-3.0.5.jar

https://code.google.com/p/osmdroid/issues/detail?id=289#c9